# Unable to create local directories error while running Ansible in AWS Lambda

Tags: ansible, aws-lambda, ansible-2.x

I am running the following Python script which runs a playbook:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from __future__ import print_function

import json
import os
import ansible.inventory
import ansible.playbook
import ansible.runner
import ansible.constants
from ansible import utils
from ansible import callbacks

print('Loading function')

def run_playbook(**kwargs):

    stats = callbacks.AggregateStats()
    playbook_cb = callbacks.PlaybookCallbacks(verbose=utils.VERBOSITY)
    runner_cb = callbacks.PlaybookRunnerCallbacks(
        stats, verbose=utils.VERBOSITY)

    # use /tmp instead of $HOME
    ansible.constants.DEFAULT_REMOTE_TMP = '/test'

    out = ansible.playbook.PlayBook(
        callbacks=playbook_cb,
        runner_callbacks=runner_cb,
        stats=stats,
        **kwargs
    ).run()

    return out


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return main()



def main():
    out = run_playbook(
        playbook='/test/little.yml',
    )
    return(out)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And, this is my `ansible.cfg` file:

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args=-o ForwardAgent=yes
retries=2
sk_sudo_pass = yes

[defaults]
remote_user = root
host_key_checking = False
#remote_tmp     = tmp
local_tmp      = ~/tmp
```

I am getting the following error, when the lambda function is invoked:

```
START RequestId: ccfe076e-0016-11e7-befa-7ba330223a64 Version: $LATEST
module initialization error: Unable to create local directories(/home/sbx_user1080/tmp): [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/sbx_user1080'

END RequestId: ccfe076e-0016-11e7-befa-7ba330223a64
```

which **means that Ansible is not able to create the `tmp` file due to permissions problem in the container which Lambda is spinning up.**

So, how do I work around it? Also, according to [this discussion](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=616978), Lambda supports writing files to the /tmp directory. So, how do I set the `local_tmp` to that directory?

Comment: Does your code happen to be based off this by José Coelho on Medium (not sure if @JoséCoelho:2398842 is the same José)? https://medium.com/@jacoelho/ansible-in-aws-lambda-980bb8b5791b . Code looks almost identical (not a complaint), but I'm new enough to Ansible that I'm not sure if it might resemble code that is more generic than truly implying you wound up on this error/Question by following that same blog I am (that brought me here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only write to `/tmp` in an AWS Lambda environment. You can't create a `~/tmp` directory in that environment. It looks like you need to change this:

`local_tmp      = ~/tmp`

to this:

`local_tmp      = /tmp`

Comment: This seemed to work for me.  The Question didn't mention where it placed its two files relative to eachother, but [placing](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-configuration-settings-locations) `ansible.cfg` in same path as the py script seems to work.